# How can I test deep link through command line for multiword destinations?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

Here is a command line for single line destination according to this [codelab](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-navigation?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fjetpack-compose-for-android-developers-3%3Fhl%3Den#7)

```
adb shell am start -d "rally://single_account/Checking" -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

I just want to test this command line with a multiword destination like this:

```
adb shell am start -d "rally://single_account/"Home Savings" -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```

Which gives me an error `Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent`.
How can I resolve this kind of destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tries I've found this works:

```
 adb shell am start -d "rally://single_account/'Home Savings'" -a android.intent.action.VIEW
```